# How to run Python code through multiple function definitions (2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I am brand new to Python so please try to go easy on me.  I have worked on an assignment for several hours and have hit a rode block.  Basically, I need to have Python write a text file containing up to 1000 random integers and have it present the max, min, and a user selected ith number.  (For example if the user entered 9 it would return the 9th variable).  We then need to have the program sort the numbers from least to greatest and return the outputs of the new list of integers. I have gotten it to write the file successfully, but I need to divide the program into several functions.  A readList(infile, first) function, a sort(first) function, and a main() function for the body of the program.  I cannot have any print statements in the read or sort functions which is confusing me.  I have tried to divide my code into these three functions and now it will not run and it gives no error message.  It does tell me that a bunch of my variables are assigned but never used because I have then in different functions.  It was also telling me earlier that I had a missing indentation in my main() function, but I could never find it.

Here is my code:

```
import random
with open("1000.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in range(1000):
        f.write(str(random.randint(0, 9999))+"\n")



def readList(infile, first):
    infile = raw_input("Please enter the file name: ")
    file_name = open(infile, 'r')
    List = file_name.readlines()
    n = int(raw_input("please enter the nth number in the list you would like to find: "))
    m = int(float(n-1))
    return List
    return m



def sortList():
    readList(infile, first)
    new_list = List.sort()
    new_min_val = new_list(min)
    new_max_val = new_list(max)
    return new_list
    return new_min_val
    return new_max_value


def main():
    readList(infile, first)
    user_num = List[m]
    first = List[0]
    lines = len(List)
    minimum_val = List(min)
    maximum_val = List(max)
    if m > 1000:
        print (m, "is greater than 1000!")
    elif m > lines:
        print ("There aren't that many numbers in the list!")
    elif lines < 1000:
        print ("WARNING: only", lines, "numbers were read into the list!")
    print (user_num)
    print (minimum_val)
    print (maximum_val)
```

I'm sorry for such a long post.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you have been given this assignment without a proper introduction to programming in Python?Your code is only generating the file with the random integers. All the rest are function definitions which are never called, which is why nothing else happens. Refer to the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how your program could look like. Maybe it helps you getting familiar with python. It may not be perfect, but at least it should work :)

```
import random
with open("1000.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in range(1000):
        f.write(str(random.randint(0, 9999))+"\n")

def readList():
    infile = raw_input("Please enter the file name: ")
    rawList = list()    
    with open(infile, 'r') as infi:
        for line in infi:
            rawList.append(int(line))
    sortedList = sortList(rawList) #function call for sorting the list, returned sorted list is stored
    n = int(raw_input("please enter the nth number in the list you would like to find: "))
    m = int(float(n-1))
    return sortedList, m

def sortList(inpList): #function needs list as input and returns sorted list
    inpList.sort() 
    return inpList

if __name__=='__main__': #This is how the main is defined in python
    sortedList, user_num = readList() #function call of readList, returned two objects are stored in variables
    first = sortedList[0] 
    lines = len(sortedList)
    minimum_val = min(sortedList)
    maximum_val = max(sortedList)
    if user_num > 1000:
        print user_num, "is greater than 1000!" # you don't need brackets when printing
    elif user_num > lines:
        print "There aren't that many numbers in the list!"
    elif lines < 1000:
        print "WARNING: only", lines, "numbers were read into the list!"
    print user_num
    print minimum_val
    print maximum_val
```

Comment: using print without () is a bad practice because 'print "something"' will not work on python 3.  Writing 'print("something")' will _always_ work under every version.  However, the OP's code should _not_ have a space between the 'print' and the '(' ...